# Get last 25 chat messages(document) from firestore ? (Android/Java)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a chat application where I want to:
- get last 25 messages 
- sorted in ascending order.

Code: (Not Working)

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("chats")
                .document(chatUid).collection("allchats")
                .orderBy("chat_datesent",Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(25)
                .orderBy("chat_datesent",Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots,Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
         if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {
             String dated;
             for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                //body
       }
       }
  });
```

Here, I tried using the first `OrderBy` just to get last 25 document because `limittolast()` isn't possible in 
firestore.

How can I achieve this? Do I have to use composite indexing? 
Please help.

Comment: Please post your database structure

Comment: why are you using `.orderBy()`  2 times with different sorting order

Comment: @RahulGaur I was trying to check if it works but it doesnot. All I want is to query  last 25 documents sorted in ascending order. Can you please help?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the last 25 messages using [Ashish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60451485/7948109), and you can sort the chat list, after receiving the data

```
        firebaseFirestore.collection("chats")
                .document(chatUid).collection("allchats")
                .orderBy("chat_datesent", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(25)
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {
                            String dated;
                            for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                                //now here you have the list as you wanted but it is not sorted
                                //simply sort the list using something like this

                                //here receive the data in POJO class
                                // assuming you have saved your chat data in chatList

                                Collections.sort(chatList, (item1, item2) -> {
                                    int firstChat = item1.chatDateSent() ? 0 : 1;
                                    int secondChat = item2.chatDateSent() ? 0 : 1;

                                    return first - second; // Ascending
                                }); // using JAVA 1_8
                                //now your list is sorted ASC, notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Please let me know if you need more help

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks a lot Rahul. Although, isn't it possible to get it get the sorted result right from the server?

Comment: This can create issues, for example: If a user sends a new message, it will be displayed at the top instead of bottom.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of two Orderby with same field

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("chats")
                .document(chatUid).collection("allchats")
                .orderBy("chat_datesent",Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(25)
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots,Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
         if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {
             String dated;
             for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                //body
       }
       }
  });
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer.  Although, If I use your code it displays first 25 documents. I want to fetch last 25 documents.

Comment: Try changing the `Direction` to `DESCENDING`

Comment: @RahulGaur Yes. But how can I sort it back to ascending? Just think of a chat  scenario. I could use collections.sort() but I want to sort it through the query itself.

Comment: Is there any button to change the sorting order ?